# Wordpress webstie as booklet: thematic vs underscore vs?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have never developed Wordpress website from scratch or from default template or from parent theme or from starter theme. I mean, I have maintained already created WP websites.

However, now I want to try to create WP from the beginning. I have mock up of website that is something liek booklet, this means, that it has many pages (about 40) and all pages differes with content - some has images, some has additional graphics, some has text etc. Website consists mainly of static pages with different layout.

What are your suggestions for newby... Previosly i have read much about underscore and thematic and I like both. Are tehre suitable for my purpsoes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use [undersores.me](http://undersores.me) as a starter theme for the following reasons:

1. I don't have to dig trough the parent theme documentation for hooks and filters
2. It is not bloated with unnecessary functions
3. Download package is customized with your theme name and slug, meaning that functions have appropriate prefixes/names